# Passing a socket object to another activity on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

and thanks in advance for your help.

What is the best practice to pass objects between activities in Android? I read of the possibility to pass serializable objects as strings by adding them to a bundle by putExtras, and than starting the next intent with it. But is a Socket serializable?

I want to pass instances of Socket , PrintWriter , BufferedReader, After the main activity opened a connection and in/out streams, so the next intent can close etc..

I would also like to know if there are other/better options to consider, because i guess there are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to either use public static variables or a wrapper class that uses the singleton pattern.

Comment: Thanks @SimonSays.
1) is the use of static variables common and recommended for doing this? what are the disadvantage of the use of static variables?
2) both activities i'd like to pass the objects between obviously extend Activity class already. can you give me an example of how would you go around wrapping them with another class with the singleton variables?

Comment: 1. i would not say the use of static variables is recommended, but sometimes it it just the easiest way of passing objects around. me personally, i try to avoid it when possible, but still use it in come cases. the disadvantage is that you don't know when the objects will get garbage collected. 2. it is the other way around. you could wrap your stream objects in a singleton, not the activities.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to start a service you can create a global variable.

Create a Singleton pattern for that socket like this:

```
public class SocketSingleton {


private static Socket socket;

public static void setSocket(Socket socketpass){
    SocketSingleton.socket=socketpass;
}

public static Socket getSocket(){
    return SocketSingleton.socket;
    //return socket;
}
```

}

Then in the code just change the global value:

```
        public void changeScreen(Socket socket, String ip, int port) {
        SocketSingleton.setSocket(socket);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ControlActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("ip", ip);
        i.putExtra("port",port);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```